# ASP.NET Identity CookieAuthentication - Returning Success but failing to login?

Tags: vb.net

I have a legacy web application on .net framework 4.8.

It appears (seemingly random, but likely not) that authentication will not work.
Not work is vague, specifically:

```
signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=False)
```

Will return `Success` but then  `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will return false and i'm directed back to the login URL.

Trying to debug this further has proved difficult. What I've noticed is that when the authentication fails, the only cookie that is set at the login screen is `__AntiXsrfToken` and notably the `ASP.NET_SessionId` is missing.

In cases where the SessionID cookie is present the login function works as expected. What I am unable to determine is why sometimes this cookie is getting set while other times it is not.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this further? Some bug I'm not aware of?

Startup.Auth.vb Code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
            .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
        .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})
```

Comment: Have your been able to replicate this yourself?  Only asking because if it's only being reported by some users maybe the issue is at the client end, perhaps disallowed all cookies or something